# AngularJS - Routing with different controllers leads to empty $scope

Tags: angularjs

This is my .js File for the routing:

```
var app = angular.module('WebApp', ['ngRoute']);

/**
 * Configure the Routes
 */
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  // Home
  .when("/", { templateUrl: "partials/kalendar.php", controller: "Ctrl" })
  .when("/logout", { templateUrl: "partials/logout.php", controller: "PageCtrl" })
  .otherwise({
    controller: function () {
        window.location.replace('/');
    },
    template: "<div></div>"
  });
}]);

/**
 * Controls all other Pages
 */
app.controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log("Page Controller reporting for duty.");
});

/**
 * Controls calendar view
 */
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log("Controller reporting for duty.");
$scope.updateDuration = function () {
        alert($scope.dateIn);
}
});
```

And this is part of my kalendar.php:

```
<div>
<label>Datum:</label>
<div class="input-group input-append date">
     <input type="text" class="span2 form-control" ng-model="dateIn">
     <span class="input-group-addon">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
     </span>
</div>
</div>
```

When I run my program, the Page Controller is called ("Controller reporting for duty." show in console), but the alert doesn't work, because $scope.dateIn is undefined. Please help me find my mistake.

Comment: you are not calling `updateDuration ()` , how would alert statement execute?

Answer (score 0):

where your calling updateDuration function in your Html??make sure your calling your function from htmm like below

```js
var app = angular.module('WebApp', ['ngRoute']);



/**
 * Controls all other Pages
 */
app.controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log("Page Controller reporting for duty.");
});

/**
 * Controls calendar view
 */
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log("Controller reporting for duty.");
$scope.updateDuration = function () {
        alert($scope.dateIn);
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="WebApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>
<label>Datum:</label>
<div class="input-group input-append date">
     <input type="text" class="span2 form-control" ng-model="dateIn">
     <span class="input-group-addon">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
     </span>
     <button type="button" ng-click="updateDuration() ">check me</button>
</div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here i managed to call the function in button click.

Comment: Thank you. I am calling the function from a clockpicker on afterDone. I am also using a datepicker in the above example. If I type the date in manually the data (for example: "12.09.2017") is alerted correctly. But if I choose it with the picker it's still undefined. Do you have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: are those both pickers are in same controller??your saying like if u use datepicker ur able to get date alert but if u use clockpicker ur not getting the alert.....if this is the actual problem please make sure that functional calling is in correct way and the function available for that controller

Comment: They are all in the same controller. The problem is: the pickers (datepicker and two clockpickers) all have input fields and if you click on them they show a pop up to choose date/time. If I just type in the date, without using the popup everything works fine. But if I use the popups $scope.dateIn (for example) is always undefined. Is this a problem of the pickers or am I overseeing something? I'm stuck on this whole problem for quite a while, so sorry for the many questions!

Comment: if u give me a plunker with the problem i can provide a solution buddy

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tFUxfK2TM3czo6OCCkPD?p=preview    I've never worked with plunker before, so I don't know if it's possible to upload directorys. My datepicker and clockpicker are located on the server I want to run this project on, so they don't work with the local paths here....I am using this datepicker: [link] https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/     and this clockpicker: [link] https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/  thanks in advantage